# queries on using xml

Tags: xml

Person.xml

```
<person>
  <PID>
   <Name>John</Name>
   <fruit>Orange</fruit>
  </PID>
  <PID>
   <Name>Wendy</Name>
   <fruit>Apple</fruit>
  </PID>
  <PID>
   <Name>Alex</Name>
   <fruit>Kiwi</fruit>
  </PID>
 </person>
```

Store.xml

```
<store>
  <AU>
   <name>Star</name>
   <fruit>Orange</fruit>
  </AU>
  <AU>
   <name>Moon</name>
   <fruit>Apple</fruit>
  </AU>
 </store>
```

I have the above two xml files and I need to write an xquery code to find out which type of fruit that a person eats that is not available in the store. How do I write the code to check which fruit is not available in the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This query** (which happens to be a pure XPath 2.0 expression):

```
doc('file:///c:/temp/delete/person.xml')
   /*/*/fruit
        [not(.
            =
             doc('file:///c:/temp/delete/store.xml')
                /*/*/fruit)
        ]
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<fruit>Kiwi</fruit>
```

**Explanation**:

Use of the general comparison operator `=` (as contrasted to the value comparison operator `eq`)

Comment: yes the code above works.but can i know how does the code below work.

[not(. =

what does the fullstop and equals mean here ?  " (.= "
            =

Comment: @setiasetia, By the definition of the `=` operator in XPath 2.0 (which is a true subset of XQuery), "When evaluating a general comparison in which either operand is a sequence of items, an implementation may return true as soon as it finds an item in the first operand and an item in the second operand that have the required magnitude relationship" -- this is identical text in both the XPath 2.0 and in the XQuery 1.0 specs. This means that if one of the operands of `=` is a sequence, the comparison is `true()` only if it has an item that is `=` to the other operand -- otherwise -- `false()` .

Comment: @setiasetia: See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xquery-20101214/#id-general-comparisons and here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-general-comparisons